# Fallback Mechanism - OWA Onsend Addin - Manifest XML

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-app

Is there any fallback mechanism for OnSend Addin s.

The scenario is my onSend addin blocks the email sending and based on some logic that returns true/false based on which email is either sent /cancelled.

Now, if my server where the web addin is hosted goes down, does this mean the end-user who has this addin configured would not be able to send mail and this is a blocker for mails.

Is there any fallback, just in case an add-in fails to load or server is down.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the feature is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page.](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.